# Proving a trajectory is critical for an action functional

Tags: calculus, analysis, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

Suppose a particle with mass $m$ moves freely in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ under the influence of a conservative force field with potential $\Phi\in C^{2}([t_{1},t_{2}]\times\mathbb{R}^{n})$; that is, its trajectory $u:[t_{1},t_{2}]\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ satisfies $m\ddot{u}=-\Phi_{u}(t,u)$ for $t\in [t_{1},t_{2}]$.

I'm trying to show that for fixed boundary values $u$ is critical for the action functional $J$ given by $$J(u)=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}F(t,u(t),\dot{u}(t))dt,\qquad F(t,u,v)=\frac{m}{2}|v|^{2}-\Phi(t,u).$$

Thus, we have $$F(t,u(t),\dot{u}(t))=\frac{m}{2}|\dot{u}(t)|^{2}-\Phi(t,u(t)).$$

Let $u(t_{1})$ and $u(t_{2})$ be fixed. Then $$\begin{aligned} J(u)&=\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\left(\frac{m}{2}|\dot{u}(t)|^{2}-\Phi(t,u(t)\right)dt \\ &=\frac{m}{2}\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}|\dot{u}(t)|^{2}dt-\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\Phi(t,u(t))dt.\end{aligned}$$

Note that $\Phi_{u}(t,u(t))=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\Phi(t,u(t))=-m\ddot{u}(t)$. Therefore $$\begin{aligned}\int\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\Phi(t,u(t))du&=-m\ddot{u}(t)\int du \\ & =-m\ddot{u}(t)\cdot u(t)+C =\Phi(t,u(t))\end{aligned}.$$

Hence $$J(u)=\frac{m}{2}\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}|\dot{u}(t)|^{2}dt+\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}(m\ddot{u}(t)\cdot u(t)+C)dt.$$

However, I feel as though I am going in the wrong direction.

**Edit:** Using the correction: $$\int\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\Phi(t,u(t))du = -m\int\ddot{u}(t)\frac{du}{dt}dt = -m\int\ddot{u}(t)\dot u(t)dt = -\frac m2 \dot u^2 + C$$

I still end up with

$$\begin{aligned} J(u)&=\frac{m}{2}\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}|\dot{u}(t)|^{2}dt+\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}\left(\frac{m}{2}\dot{u}(t)^{2}+C\right)dt \\ &=\frac{m}{6}[|u(t)|^{3}]^{t_{2}}_{t_{1}}+[\frac{m}{6}u(t)^{3}+Ct]^{t_{2}}_{t_{1}} \\ &=\frac{m}{6}(|u(t_{2})|^{3}-|u(t_{1})|^{3})+\frac{m}{6}(u(t_{2})^{3}-u(t_{1})^{3})+C(t_{2}-t_{1})\end{aligned}$$

which is not equal to zero.

Comment: I should have double-checked before I answered, but your use of $u$ as a variable for differtiation gulled me into thinking it was into $\Bbb R$, not $\Bbb R^n$. My answer applies when $u$ is a scalar, not a vector. But then your whole calculation does as well. There is no such thing as $\frac\partial{\partial u}$ (at least, not as you mean it). You need to clarify what you mean by $\Phi_u$. Then the rest of the calculation can make sense.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Then I guess it would be $\nabla_{u}\Phi$.

Comment: Why not just write the Euler Lagrange equations?

Answer (score 1):

$\ddot u$ is not independent of $u$. I.e.,
$$\int\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\Phi(t,u(t))du \ne-m\ddot{u}(t)\int du$$

In fact $$\int\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\Phi(t,u(t))du = -m\int\ddot{u}(t)\frac{du}{dt}dt = -m\int\ddot{u}(t)\dot u(t)dt = -\frac m2 \dot u^2 + C$$

Comment: Check the edit.